# Swap content on scroll but keep screen fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to achieve this concept, but I'm having some frustration after trying long, convoluted methods that are still causing glitches on mobile, Firefox, etc.

The concept is this:
[image]

There are two headlines on the left and right of the page. The one on the left is focused first, and its text is visible while Headline 2 is grayed out and its text is hidden.

Then, if you scroll down, switch the focus to Headline 2, show its text, and hide the text of Headline 1.

Is this just not cleanly achievable? It started out as a fun "what if" concept that I just can't let go.

Currently, I'm trying something like this to capture the scroll:

```
var lastScrollTimeout;
var scrollDetectionLocked = false;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll', function(e) {

    // do nothing if still locked
    if ( scrollDetectionLocked === true )
        return false;

    // lock it
    scrollDetectionLocked = true;

    // perform operations if not locked
    var direction;
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop)// scrolled down
        direction = -1;
    else // scrolled up
        direction = 1;

    lastScrollTop = st;

    console.log('doScroll('+direction+')');



    clearTimeout(lastScrollTimeout)
    lastScrollTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        // unlock it after certain time
        scrollDetectionLocked = false;
    }, timeoutBetweenScrolls);


});
```

The `doScroll()` function just sees which Headline/text is currently loaded, and loads the next/previous one accordingly.

However, the console output is sometimes wrong, saying it should `doScroll(1)` (up) when it should be `doScroll(-1)` (down) among other things. It just isn't a clean solution in my opinion.

I believe the issue is caused because all elements are fixed on the screen, and the only scrollable item is an element called `.fake-scroll`. This started out as a fix for mobile phones which don't allow `e.originalEvent.wheelDelta`, and again, just seems messy.

I've messed with parallax scrolling, but didn't think I could use it to achieve this effect. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Aside from the "Main | Alt" nav links not staying fixed and the "More" submenu not working, this example shows the last semi-working example I had. https://jsfiddle.net/0vju51ba

Comment: can you give us fiddle / snippet to play around?

Comment: Aside from the "Main | Alt" nav links not staying fixed and the "More" submenu not working, this example shows the last semi-working example I had. https://jsfiddle.net/0vju51ba/

Comment: Will offer a bounty in 2 days.